# Trying to get the time of an operation and receiving time 0 seconds

Tags: c, time

I am trying to see how much does it take for about 10000 names to be inserted into a BST(writing in c).

I am reading these names from a txt file using fscanf. I have declared a file pointer(fp) at the main function. Calling a function that is at another .c file passing the fp through its arguments. I want to count the time needed for 2,4,8,16,32...,8192 names to be inserted saving the time at a long double array.  I have included the time.h library at the .c file where the function is located.

Code:

```
void myfunct(BulkTreePtr *Bulktree, FILE* fp,long double time[])
{
    double tstart, tend, ttemp;
    TStoixeioyTree datainput;
    int error = 0,counter=0,index=0,num=2,i;
    tstart =  ((double) clock())/CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    while (!feof(fp))
    {
        counter++;
        fscanf(fp,"%s %s", datainput.lname, datainput.fname);
        Tree_input(&((*Bulktree)->TreeRoot), datainput, &error);
        if (counter == num)
        {
            ttemp =  (double) clock()/CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
            time[index] = ttemp-tstart;
            num = num * 2;
            index++;
        }   
    }
    tend =  ((double) clock())/CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    printf("Last value of ttemp is %f\n",ttemp-tstart);
    time[index] = (tend-tstart);
    num = 2;
    for(i=0;i<14;i++)
    {
        printf("Time after %d names is %f sec \n", num, (float)time[i]);
        num=num*2;
    }
```

I am getting this:

> Last value of ttemp is 0.000000
>   Time after 2 names is 0.000000 sec 
>   Time after 4 names is 0.000000 sec 
>   Time after 8 names is 0.000000 sec 
>   Time after 16 names is 0.000000 sec
>   
>  Time after 32 names is 0.000000
>   ms 
>  Time after 64 names is
>   0.000000 sec 
>  Time after 128 names is 0.000000 sec 
>  Time after 256
>   names is 0.000000 sec 
>  Time after
>   512 names is 0.000000 sec 
>  Time
>   after 1024 names is 0.000000 sec 
>   Time after 2048 names is 0.000000 sec
>   
>  Time after 4096 names is 0.000000
>   sec 
>  Time after 8192 names is
>   0.000000 sec 
>  Time after 16384 names is 0.010000 sec

What am I doing wrong? :S

Comment: Why you're casting time[] in within printf()? Is it not double?

Comment: Please post the whole code, f.e. the if block inside the while is essential and it's likely the error is in there.

Comment: It is also odd that "sec" in the printf shows up as "ms". What does the real code look like?

Comment: time[] is a long double :S
Posted the whole code.
The sec and ms is fixed. Changed a bit the code I posted here. Now it is the same.

Comment: Why not adding adding some parenthesis here: ttemp =  (double) clock()/CLOCKS_PER_SEC;

Answer (score 1):

Use clock_getres() and clock_gettime().  Most likely you will find your system doesn't have a very fast clock.  Note that the system might return different numbers when calling gettimeofday or clock_gettime(), but often times (depending on kernel) those numbers at greater than HZ resolution are lies generated to simulate time advancing.

You might find a better test to do fixed time tests.  Find out how many inserts you can do in 10 seconds.  Or have some kind of fast reset method (memset?) and find out how many groups of inserts of 1024 names you can do in 10 seconds.

[EDIT]

Traditionally, the kernel gets interrupted at HZ frequency by the hardware.  Only when it gets this hardware interrupt does it know that time had advanced by 1/HZ of a second.  The traditional value for HZ was 1/100 of a second.  Surprise, surprise, you saw a 1/100th of a second increment in time.  Now some systems and kernels have recently started providing other methods of getting higher resolution time, looking at the RTC device or whatever.

However, you should use the clock_gettime() function I pointed you to along with the clock_getres() function to find out how often you will get accurate time updates.  Make sure your test runs many many multiples of clock_getres() unless you want it to be a total lie.

Comment: What do you mean that my system doesn't have a fast clock?:S
I am really new to all these as it is my first year in university.
I am using ubuntu.

Comment: @Chris: See updated answer discussing HZ and recommending again that you look at clock_getres() and have a test longer than that.

Comment: This is about an assingment for the university and I can't really afford the time to check these 2 functions as I am not understanding completely some of the things you mention. :S
Thank you for your time Seth!

Comment: @Chris: I find it difficult to understand why you bothered asking the question if you are unwilling to do the things necessary to solve your problem.  However, as I said, you don't need to use those other functions.  Those other functions just allow you to quantify how long your test needs to be to be accurate.  The only solution is to make your test longer, which doesn't require switching what function you use to measure the test with since you found out experimentally that the system gives 1/100 second granularity.  Using clock_getres() would just allow you to dynamically this out.

Comment: The thing was that I was in a hurry to finish my assingment.
I can reply now and hope that you can help me understand the things you've mentioned.
Why should I have a fast reset method? A fast reset method of what? Why should I try memset? :S
I didn't want to test when I am going to get accurate time updates I wanted to start a timer and then stop it when I wanted and kept that time at a variable..used gettimeofday and was succesful.

Comment: @Chris: A fast reset mechanism means that resetting to re-run the test will not greatly affect the test.  If you do `clock_gettime(); for(x=0;x<1000000;x++) { reset_test(T);  do_test(T); } clock_gettime();` you want to make sure the stuff OTHER than do_test will not dominate the test time.  Of course, you can comment out the do_test() call, find out how long it takes, and then subtract that part back out.  The number of tests needs to be pretty large to do such games accurately.  You can repeat this several times to check for stability doing the standard discard/average technique.

Answer (score 0):

clock() returns the number of "ticks"; there are CLOCKS_PER_SEC ticks per second. For any operation which takes less than 1/CLOCKS_PER_SEC seconds, the return value of clock() will either be unchanged or changed by 1 tick.

From your results it looks like even 16384 insertions take no more than 1/100 seconds.

If you want to know how long a certain number of insertions take, try repeating them many, many times so that the total number of ticks is significant, and then divide that total time by the number of times they were repeated.

Comment: But other colleagues got it working right with only one measurement :S

Comment: @Chris: They may have gotten a NUMBER with one measurement (there are several system calls, like gettimeofday, which will pretend to return sub-HZ accuracy), but it was not accurate assuming they were running the same length test on the same system.  It would be trivial to run a longer test and get good results.

Answer (score 0):

`clock` returns the amount of cpu time used, not the amount of actual time elapsed, but that might be what you want here. Note that Unix standards requires `CLOCKS_PER_SECOND` to be exactly one million (1000000), but the resolution can be much worse (e.g. it might jump by 10000 at a time). You should be using `clock_gettime` with the cpu time clock if you want to measure cpu time spent, or otherwise with the monotonic clock to measure realtime spent.

Answer (score 0):

ImageMagick includes stopwatch functions such as these.

```
#include "magick/MagickCore.h"
#include "magick/timer.h"

TimerInfo *timer_info;
timer_info = AcquireTimerInfo();
<your code>
printf("elapsed=%.6f sec", GetElapsedTime(timer_info));
```

But that only seems to have a resolution of 1/100 second. Plus it requires installing ImageMagic. I suggest this instead. It's simple and has usec resolution in Linux.

```
#include <time.h>  
double timer(double start_secs)
{   
    static struct timeval  tv;
    static struct timezone tz;
    gettimeofday(&tv, &tz);
    double now_secs = (double)tv.tv_sec + (double)tv.tv_usec/1000000.0;
    return now_secs - start_secs;
}

double t1 = timer(0);
<your code>
printf("elapsed=%.6f sec", timer(t1));
```